# Show all posts if fields empty

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

```
// Start the Query
$v_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'wpcf-services',
            'value' => $services,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'listing-city',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $location,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'listing-category',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $listing_category,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
);

$listingsearch = new WP_Query( $v_args );
```

I want to show all posts in search results if field is empty. If either `tax_query` or `meta_query` is left blank, show all posts in search results.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?  if(isset($services)&&$services!=""){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'     => 'wpcf-services',
                'value'   => $services,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                );
        }


         $tax_query = array('relation'=>'AND');

          if(isset($location)&&$location!=""){
             $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'listing-city',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $location,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                );
            }  


        if(isset($listing_category)&&$listing_category!=""){
             $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'listing-category',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $listing_category,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                );
            }     


        $v_args = array(
            'post_type'  =>  'listing',
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'tax_query' =>$tax_query,

        );

 $listingsearch = new WP_Query( $v_args );?>
```

This should work for you.
It would check the empty and if found, it will fetch all the products. Else it would fetch accordingly. Let me know if any more suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may mean this ?:

```
$v_args = array(
'post_type'     =>  'listing',
'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key'     => 'wpcf-services',
            'value'   => empty($services)?'%':$services,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            ),
'tax_query' =>array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'listing-city',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => empty($location)?'%':$location,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'listing-category',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => empty($listing_category)?'%':$listing_category,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        ),

);
```